# How to make a partial LIMIT in a SQL Select

Tags: mysql, count, limit, where-clause

I know that with a LIMIT at the end of a SQL statement, like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM books WHERE 1 LIMIT 3
```

it will show at most 3 items from table `books`.

Now imagine that we have a field, `category` and filter by it:

```
 SELECT * FROM books WHERE category IN (1, 3, 5) LIMIT 3
```

I will get those rows with category with values 1 OR 3 OR 5, and again a limit of rows of 3.

How can I get a limit of 3 for each category? (outline of basic idea)

```
 SELECT * FROM books WHERE category IN (1, 3, 5) LIMITS (3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: use mysql subquery

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` produces indeterminate results. The same query executed twice on the same data can return different results. Use `ORDER BY` to produce consistent results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a `UNION`:

```
(SELECT * FROM books WHERE category = 1 LIMIT 3)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM books WHERE category = 3 LIMIT 3)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM books WHERE category = 5 LIMIT 3)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Just add parentheses (make them subqueries)

Answer (score 0):

Along with `MySQL user defined variables` you can achieve this:

```
SELECT 
t.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF( @sameCategory = category , @rn := @rn + 1,
         IF(@sameCategory := category, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
    ) AS rowNumber
    FROM books
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameCategory := 0, @rn := 1) var
    ORDER BY category 
) AS t
WHERE t.rowNumber <= 3
ORDER BY t.category
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `LIMIT` in a single query.  One method uses variables:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = category, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := category, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from books b cross join
           (select @c := -1, @rn := 0) params
      where category in (1, 2, 3)
      order by category
     ) b
where rn <= 3;
```